# Javascript remove reduce or trim strings from a string or link

Tags: javascript

I have this link/string:

```
https://link/to/a/file/filename.ext
```

My JS skills are now rusty and I need to trim the link from the last instance of `/` so that I could separate the directory and the file name (with the file extension attached to the file name).

```
var string = 'https://link/to/a/file/filename.ext';

var directory = 'https://link/to/a/file/'; // should have a value of 'https://link/to/a/file' coming from var string
var file = 'filename.ext'; // should have a value of 'filename.ext' coming from var string
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `split()` and `join()`

```js
var string = 'https://link/to/a/file/filename.ext';
const strArray = string.split('/');
var file = strArray.pop();;
var directory = strArray.join('/');

console.log(file, directory);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = 'https://link/to/a/file/filename.ext';     
directory = string.substring(0, string.lastIndexOf("/"));
console.log(directory);
file = string.substr(string.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
console.log(file);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I kinda expect that more variation of these answers would pop up in this question

Answer (score 1):

### `/` In the search parameters

The other solutions split the whole url at the last `/`, but in practice you *can* have situations where the search parameters contain a `/`. For example, a redirect parameter for a single sign on.

The example below uses the `URL` object to parse the URL first so that you don't have to mess with that, then uses just the path name to get the parts you want:

```js
//Based on a real SSO url
var u = new URL('https://idp.blarg.edu/made/up/url/file.ext?service=https://some.webservice.blarg.edu/some/thing/on/the/internet.net?FolderPath=thingy.CO_EMPLOYEE_SELF_SERVICE.BLARG%26IsFolder=false%26IgnoreParamTempl=FolderPath%2cIsFolder%26');

// Split the path only on the last /, (no url params)
// I like a regex here cause it splits exactly into 2, but split() may be more readable...
[_, path, file] = u.pathname.match('^(.*)/([^/]*)$');

console.log(u.origin + path);
console.log(file);
```